# How can a Bavarian cream that includes orange juice thicken with so much liquid?

Tags: dessert, thickening, dairy, creme-anglaise

I found a recipe for an orange flavored Bavarian cream with the following directions.

Start with a crème anglaise by whisking egg yolks and sugar and then add boiling milk flavored with orange zest. Put the mixture back on the heat and -- here comes the fishy part -- *add fresh orange juice and let everything thicken*.

Then it continues to add softened gelatine, let cool and add whipped cream. But this makes sense.

How is a mixture so liquid supposed to thicken? Is this the right procedure to make a flavored Bavarian cream?

Comment: You ask about proportions, but don't give any numbers. That means we can only speculate

Comment: I didn't :) was hoping to have a feel for how much sense these directions had. Adding whipped cream to a liquid cream might not make much sense, but after gelatine is added to the latter, maybe it does.

Answer (score 6):

The egg yolks can thicken the liquid when you heat it, like in a standard egg custard (the home made version, not the one made from custard powder). But this is a fairly tricky procedure: if you heat it too much the mixture will separate. So best done on a double boiler (*'bain marie'*).

And in addition, you have the whipped cream and the gelatine, which will help thicken the mixture on cooling*. I suspect that there's also a prescribed time in the refrigirator...

(*: as I've been taught, the swollen gelatine is first dissolved in a small amount of liquid, and the whipped cream is mixed with the rest when the gelatine just starts to set)

Comment: Also: a crème anglaise is supposed to flow, like cream, rather than set, like a baked custard or flan.

Comment: Pure crème anglaise, yes, indeed. But then, you don't add gelatine to it.

Comment: I know; the recipe _starts_ with a crème anglaise and I wanted to emphasize to him that at that stage it would only be a bit thicker than cream.